# Laravel 4 Eloquent assign BIT values

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to set a filed with `BIT` data type in mySql using Eloquent.

```
$i = new Step;
$i->active = 'b0';
$i->save();
```

But the `active` filed is `1`, I also tried:

```
$i->active = "b'0'";
$i->active = '0';
$i->active = false;
...
```

Simply I want to run something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO `steps` (`active`) VALUES (b'0')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704052/laravel-4-2-bit-datatype-issue?noredirect=1#27704314

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Talking about `active` field:**
If you want to use `active` and `inactive` for flagging `active` and `inactive` state of any record (i.e. user model) then you may use `tinyint` data type.

> Bool, Boolean: These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of
>   zero is considered false. Non-zero values are considered true.

## Soft Deleting

Also, Laravel provides built-in mechanism for this kind of operation using a `deleted_at` field in the table which is known as [soft delete](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting). Read more on the manual link given here, it's easy to implement and use.