# Laravel 4.2 BIT datatype issue

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, bit

there is a `bit(1)` type column in database table. but its not working as i expected.

**problem is**

```
$invitee = new Invitee();
$invitee->name = "name1";
$invitee->email = "example@mail.com";
$invitee->isActive = 0;    // "b'0'", '0', false,   are also not working
$invitee->save();
```

I need to put a zero `0` in the `isActive` column but its getting value `1` every time when i try to add a record with a `0`.

and i found a question in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799952/laravel-4-eloquent-assign-bit-values). but the answers are not describing the cause of the problem. glad if someone can explain the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you want `bit` for something like seems to be `boolean`?

Comment: yes, cant change the database :(

Comment: Did you try `$invitee->isActive = "\0001";`? The BIT in MySQL works differently than bool, so you cannot check for 1 or 2. The BIT(m) values range from 1-64. If you would just insert a 1 it will be padded with zeros, for example, assigning a value of b'101' to a BIT(6) column is, in effect, the same as assigning b'000101'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Having `bit` type field means that you need to use raw values as a workaround whenever you are inserting/updating that field.

That's because PDO by default will bind these values and they will be treated as strings, thus `bit` will result in `1`:

```
DB::table('table')->insert(['bit_field' => 0]); // inserts 1
DB::table('table')->insert(['bit_field' => DB::raw(0)]); // inserts 0
```

And I suggest changing it to `tinyint` if you could.