# BIT datat type rendering issue in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a bit type column in database table. First I was having problem saving field which solved by this question [Laravel 4.2 BIT datatype issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704052/laravel-4-2-bit-datatype-issue)

But now when I retrieve data i a getting that bit type field as {}.

```
"active": {}
```

Please help me if anyone has solution.

Edit:
Sorry, the problem is while creating object.

I have a "schedule" table in which I have "active" field which is BIT. When I create new Schedule using laravel eloquent, returned object has 'active' field as emptystring {}, No matter bit value is 0 or 1.

```
$schedule = Schedule::create($input);
```

returns

```
{
      "active": {},
      "cityId": 84,
      "eventdate": "2015-09-01T00:00:00+05:30",
      "updatedon": "2015-09-15 16:53:48",
      "createdon": "2015-09-15 16:53:48"
}
```

Comment: in that question it self suggested change bit to tinyint right?

Comment: And show me your query also,we can easily understand your problem

Comment: change to bit to tinyint is right but i can't change database definition.

Comment: ok k look at my answer and try.

Comment: I have edited my question, please look at it.

Comment: i want your retrieve process,how do you retrieve your Schedule table values,i want that code.

Comment: I am using laravel eloquent's function to retrieve data `EventSchedule::all()` but it's working fine, problem is in returned object while creating new schedule.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem, i have done like this.

Normally i have retrieve like this but failed to get the email data.In this case email datatype is BIT.

```
$query = "SELECT Username, email FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
```

after that i have tried like this and it's working fine for me.

```
$query = "SELECT Username, CAST(email AS unsigned integer) AS emailid FROM users";
```