# Laravel 5.8 BIT(1) datatype issue

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a column enabled with datatype bit(1). I am trying to save 0 or 1 value in Database by Laravel eloquent.

```
$model->enabled = $inputs['enabled'];
$model->save();
```

I have saved values in my config file.

```
'enabled' => [
    '0' => 'No',
    '1' => 'Yes',
],
```

But when I tried to save these value in database. I was getting error like,

**SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'enabled' at row 1**

when i ran query in mysql phpmyadmin, it saved data correctly database.

But running this query by eloquent, it produces error.

Comment: It seems you are saving data ' 'No', 'Yes' that is string not 0 or 1

Comment: by doing var_dump($inputs['enabled']); it shows me 0 or 1. it produces error on save();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 4.2 BIT datatype issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704052/laravel-4-2-bit-datatype-issue)

Answer (score 3):

you need tinyint type, in your migration file do

```
$table->boolean('enabled')->default(false);
```

When you migrate with `boolean('column_name')` it creates a column with type tinyint(1) and you can set to model true/1 or false/0 and save. For example

```
$model->boolean_field = true;
$model->save();
```

Or

```
$model->boolean_field = 1;
$model->save();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - why is tinyint needed?

Comment: When you migrate with boolean('column_name') it creates a column with type tinyint(1) and you can set to model true/1 or false/0 and save. For example `$model->boolean_field = true; $model->save();` It will be the same as `$model->boolean_field = 1; $model->save();`

Comment: Please add all such information to your answer by editing it. Don't put explanations in the comment section

Answer (score 1):

As per MySQL manual you can use should use  `bool` and `boolean` which are aliases of `tinyint` to store 0 or 1 value

> `TINYINT`: A value of
>   zero is considered false. Non-zero
>   values are considered true.

So use:

```
$table->tinyInteger('enabled');
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/other-vendor-data-types.html

Answer (score 1):

A boolean in mysql is generaly a tinyint.

Eloquent models can cast boolean automaticaly : https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

```
protected $casts = [
    'enabled' => 'boolean',
];
```

Before saving your model, make sure your variable is a boolean

```
$model->enabled = $inputs['enabled']==='Yes';
$model->save();
```

Comment: what if i try to save 'No' value ?

Comment: $inputs['enabled']==='Yes' returns `false` so it works

Comment: Basically i am using dropdown from where i select yes or no to save 1 or 0 value into database respectively. i have to handle both things at the same time. can you please guide me ?

Comment: so your `$inputs['enabled']` should be equal to 0 or 1 ? In this case, you should only do `$model->enabled = $inputs['enabled']` and it will works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for you response. Yes by doing so it is returning 0 or 1, but it is not saving by doing $model->save(); and producing error "String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'enabled' "

Comment: It is not possible if you have casting it to a boolean !

Comment: No i haven't casting it to boolean.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use mutator to force values.
example : in your model, append :

```
 public function setEnabled($value) // note the E in uppercase.
    {
        if ($value=='YES') { $this->attributes['enabled'] = 1;
        if ($value=='NO')  { $this->attributes['enabled'] = 0;
        if ($value=='1')  { $this->attributes['enabled'] = 1;
        if ($value=='0')  { $this->attributes['enabled'] = 0;
        // etc...
        // the logic can be improved... yes/YES/No/no/0/1/empty/null/ etc..
    }
```

and in the client code

```
   $model->enabled = 'YES'; // || 'NO' || etc..,  : note the e in lowercase.
```

then method setEnabled is called during assignation and 'enabled' will become 1

doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 0):

So i had solved my question by just adding DB::raw();

like,

```
$model->enabled = DB::raw($inputs['enabled']);
$model->save();
```

Eloquent doesn't work by calling Boolean value directly, first you have to gone through your values in DB::raw();

It works like a charm.